# Can MechanicalSoup (python 3x) deal with javascript in a website?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, mechanicalsoup

I could successfully login and navigate through a website but when I inspected the logout button it is like `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$lnkBtnLogout','')` as link, `follow_link()` doesn't work on this (saying: no adapters)??? Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you really need to log out? Probably just quiting your program would be enough (it's not always, for example I had trouble with a website allowing only one connection if I didn't log out, so this is a real question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup:

> A Python library for automating interaction with websites. MechanicalSoup automatically stores and sends cookies, follows redirects, and can follow links and submit forms. **It doesn't do JavaScript.**

This gives you two options.

## Do the JavaScript yourself

Read the JavaScript. Reverse engineer it. Reimplement it in Python. Figure out what data in the page is dynamic and needed for the algorithm. Extract that using MechanicalSoup and insert it into your reimplementation.

## Don't use MechanicalSoup

Use something which does support JavaScript (such as Selenium or PhantomJS) instead.