# Mechanicalsoup whit interactive pages (without open browser)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I have a problem with interactives pages with forms, because I have to select a element from the form and later render the current page and to scrape it

The form is a simple radio buttons, it contains an onclick action and call a js function that write in a DOM element

```
<input id="RBLOpcionBuscar_2" type="radio" name="RBLOpcionBuscar" value="Todas" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RBLOpcionBuscar$2\',\'\')', 0)" />
```

I find diferents options to get elements generated by javascript: dryscrape, requests_html, python-qt4 and selenium but I do not know how to integrate them and I do not want to use Selenium because it opens a browser

Respects!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MechanicalSoup (python 3x) how to logout a website whose logout button is a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366610/in-mechanicalsoup-python-3x-how-to-logout-a-website-whose-logout-button-is-a-j)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to select your option

```
browser["RBLOpcionBuscar"] = "Todas"
```

And then send the hidden inputs

```
 # option of query calls
 browser.get_current_form().set("__EVENTTARGET", "GVConvocatorias", True)
 # call identifier
 browser.get_current_form().set("__EVENTARGUMENT", "Page$" + str(jump_page), True)
```

here it is an example

https://github.com/danipilze/BECAS_ICETEX/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow! If you could, please make sure to use English when describing how something works (like in the code comments) as that is StackOverflow's policy. That way if someone else finds your answer useful they will be more likely to understand what you are trying to say.