# How to Load a page in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, mechanicalsoup

I need to just load my login page with my credentials entered.
I was able to enter the login details and submit using MechanicalSoup
My login page says in chrome browser:

*Note : Do not close this window, closing this window will log you out.*

How can I load the website and hold so, I won't get logged out.
For instance,

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

try:
    browser.open("http://172.16.16.16:8090/")  # starting of login site
except:
    print('No connection to Login Page')
    exit()
```

This will just load my login page(`http://172.16.16.16:8090')` but will not keep it load.  So, login will be disconnected after few time.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Since it is not clear what you mean by "loading a page in Python," please include your code and explain what you expected and what did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain HTTP/HTML, "closing a page" does not do anything, so if the website you are browsing logs you out when you close a window, it most likely means that this website uses javascript (either to trigger an event on page close with `beforeunload`, or to periodically send a request to extend the session's duration). If so, then MechanicalSoup won't help much as it does not do JavaScript.

See also: [In MechanicalSoup (python 3x) how to logout a website whose logout button is a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366610/in-mechanicalsoup-python-3x-how-to-logout-a-website-whose-logout-button-is-a-j) and [MechanicalSoup's FAQ](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails)