# MechanicalSoup not selecting a non-form input

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I want to select a input. The only problem is: the MechanicalSoup is giving me a error just by trying to select a input outside of a form.

[Login site(Outlook)](https://outlook.live.com/owa/?nlp=1)

Code:

```
import mechanicalsoup
br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
br.open('https://outlook.live.com/owa/?nlp=1')
print(br.get_url())
br.['loginfmt'] = '****************************'
br.submit_selected()
#Is here that my program gives a error, and there i stopped. (I edited the email.)
```

Comment: `br.['...']` should be `br['...']`. Probably a typo while copy-pasting the code here.

Comment: The page you are trying to browse generates HTML through JavaScript. MechanicalSoup is not the right tool for that. See [the FAQ](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MechanicalSoup (python 3x) how to logout a website whose logout button is a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366610/in-mechanicalsoup-python-3x-how-to-logout-a-website-whose-logout-button-is-a-j)