# Site returns login page again when scraping after logging in successfully once using MechanicalSoup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

Im trying to scrape some data from Twitter using BeautifulSoup as a part of a project. To scrape the ‘following’ section I need to first login, so I tried doing so using MechanicalSoup. I know the login is successful as I received an email saying so, but when I go to a different page in the same website to scrape data it again redirects me to the login page.

```py
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
    raise_on_404=True,
    user_agent='MyBot/0.1: mysite.example.com/bot_info',)
login_page = browser.get("https://twitter.com/login")
login_form = login_page.soup.findAll("form")
login_form = login_form[2]
login_form.find("input", {"name": "session[username_or_email]"})["value"] = "puturusername"
login_form.find("input", {"name": "session[password]"})["value"] = "puturpassword"
login_response = browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
login_response.soup()
```

This sent me a successful login email, upon which I tried:

```py
page_stml = browser.open('https://twitter.com/MKBHD/following').text
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
page_soup
```

I received the page containing `https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FMKBHD%2Ffollowing&amp` instead of the actual ‘following’ page.

And if I try the code given below instead of 'browser.open('https://twitter.com/MKBHD/following').text':

```py
# verify we are now logged in
page = browser.get_current_page()
print(page)
messages = page.find("div", class_="flash-messages")
if messages:
    print(messages.text)
assert page.select(".logout-form")

print(page.title.text)

# verify we remain logged in (thanks to cookies) as we browse the rest of
# the site
page3 = browser.open("https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup")
assert page3.soup.select(".logout-form”)
```

I get the output:

```
----> 4 messages = page.find("div", class_="flash-messages")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘find’
```

update:
the `login_response.soup()`
gives me the following:

```
 </style>, <body>
 <noscript>
 <center>If you’re not redirected soon, please <a href="/">use this link</a>.</center>
 </noscript>
 <script nonce="O1gf092z/sXmKkH64mLOzQ==">

       document.cookie = "app_shell_visited=1;path=/;max-age=5";

       location.replace(location.href.split("#")[0]);
     </script>
 </body>, <noscript>
 <center>If you’re not redirected soon, please <a href="/">use this link</a>.</center>
 </noscript>, <center>If you’re not redirected soon, please <a href="/">use this link</a>.</center>, <a href="/">use this link</a>, <script nonce="O1gf092z/sXmKkH64mLOzQ==">

       document.cookie = "app_shell_visited=1;path=/;max-age=5";

       location.replace(location.href.split("#")[0]);
     </script>]
```

Comment: does the site work in a browser if you disable JavaScript?

Comment: @MatthieuMoy Just tried it, it doesn’t work... Anyway to get around this?

Comment: Reading the doc ;-)? https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MechanicalSoup (python 3x) how to logout a website whose logout button is a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366610/in-mechanicalsoup-python-3x-how-to-logout-a-website-whose-logout-button-is-a-j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid to get the redirection page, you can use StatefulBrowser() object instead of Browser().

I wrote a short post about it : https://piratefache.ch/python-3-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup

```
import mechanicalsoup

if __name__ == "__main__":

    URL = "https://twitter.com/login"
    LOGIN = "your_login"
    PASSWORD = "your_password"
    TWITTER_NAME = "displayed_name" # Displayed username on Twitter

    # Create a browser object
    browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

    # request Twitter login page
    browser.open(URL)

    # we grab the login form
    browser.select_form('form[action="https://twitter.com/sessions"]')

    # print form inputs
    browser.get_current_form().print_summary()

    # specify username and password
    browser["session[username_or_email]"] = LOGIN
    browser["session[password]"] = PASSWORD

    # submit form
    response = browser.submit_selected()

    # get current page output
    response_after_login = browser.get_current_page()

    # verify we are now logged in ( get img alt element containing username )
    # if you found a better way to check, let me know. Since twitter generate dynamically all theirs classes, its
    # pretty complicated to get better information
    user_element = response_after_login.select_one("img[alt="+TWITTER_NAME+"]")

    # if username is in the img field, it means the user is successfully connected
    if TWITTER_NAME in str(user_element):
        print("You're connected as " + TWITTER_NAME)
    else:
        print("Not connected")
```

Sources:

- [StatefulBrowser](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html#statefulbrowser)
- [Example with StatefulBrowser](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#a-more-complete-example-logging-in-into-github)